# Prevent someone else from using my iCloud account?

Tags: icloud, email

I am using an Apple iCloud account that was created for me by a friend. I have a suspicion that my friend is now accessing my photos and videos through this account.

When we created the account, we used his email address for the account's rescue email address. According to Apple:

> Rescue Email Address
>
> Give us a rescue email address where we can send you a link to confirm
>   your identity and let you reset your information should any security
>   issues arise. This address is only for communicating information about
>   your security details. We won’t send any other types of messages to
>   this address.

I have changed my password many times but I believe, because of the above, he can still access the account through the rescue email address we used when we created the account.

Can you please tell me, if I changed my password, can he can find the password out using the rescue email address or not?

Comment: Does your friend have access to the email account (not the rescue email account!) related to your AppleID?

Comment: I've made an attempt to clean this one up. Please let me know if I've misunderstood the question you were asking as we'll edit it further.

Answer (score 2):

To summarize what you should do in one single answer:

1. Change the rescue email associated with the account. You can do this by going to https://appleid.apple.com/ and clicking on `Manage My Apple ID`, logging in, and then making sure all the email addresses listed in `Name, ID and Email Addresses` section of your account are email addresses that *only* *you* have the passwords to access. In particular, the `Primary Email Address` associated with the account should be an email address that you and you alone control.

[image]

1. Under the `Password and Security` section in the `Manage My Apple ID` site, change your password. Do this *after* you change the email addresses on the account so you don't accidentally lock yourself out.

While you're in there, you should make sure your mailing addresses and phone number are also assigned to identities that belong to you and you alone.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do would reset your password immediately. Unless he has access to your email account, too, he will be unable to see or get the new password, just use any other account than the iCloud email associated with your iCloud account. So, change the password as soon as you can.

Comment: In addition, change your rescue email address on appleid.apple.com to an email address only you have access to.